# converting string data into color format using razor in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on asp.net mvc4 and my question is i am getting color name from database like below

color:red
Below is my code its displaying string but i want color

```
 <span>Color <b>:</b><strong>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.color)</strong></span><div>
```

I want to convert this string that is red to color and display in my view using the razor i am new to the mvc please mentioned me the code how to implement in view

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information for anyone to be able to help much. Show us what you've tried, perhaps show some of your code and give as many details as possible. Be specific.

Comment: It really depends if you are passing a list to the view or a single record. If it's a list then something like Soner's answer is along the right lines. If its just a singular object of your 'ViewModel' then it would simply be something along the lines of @Model.Color placed wherever you want it to go.

Answer (score 0):

,Hi

You need to use foreach in view side.

As instance,

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Color().tolist())
{
if (item.color =="Red")
{
<p><font color="red">This is Red text!</font></p>
}
{
if (item.color =="Green")
{
<p><font color="Green">This is Green text!</font></p>
}
```

hope helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the this code

```
<span>Color <b>:</b>
     <strong style=@Model.color>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.color)</strong>
</span>
```

hope this will help you :)